# script resources limit when visitors over 1000 in same time

Tags: linux, nginx

I have a Linux Server (i7 / 48gb ram) that hosts just two sites.  One site is wordpress and the other is custom design php script.

When I have heavy load on the two sites ( 1000 visitor in same time ) the custom design has high response times, but when it has fewer visitors ( 100 ) the wordpress have small response times.

How do I change the limit that script or domain can use resources of the server?

The main problem is that although the server is able to host more visitors (1000 at the same time) the response time gets high.

examples :

http://maktaba.saqafa.com/

http://www.saqafa.com/article/529

Comment: I feel like this is a haiku gone terribly wrong.

Comment: ???? sorry for my bad english what you mean ?

Answer (score 1):

So, you have a crappy programmed custom stript and hen many people use it at the same time, you overload the server.

What is the question?

Your i7 likely has limited ressources - either CPU or Disc IO, RAM is unlikely (but also possible). One of those gets overloaded.

Fix?

Either distribute load over bigger hardware, or - optimize the script.

Comment: the problem is on the same cpu load the wordpress get slow and other is fast 
on low visitors the two same speed 
so what is the difference i know it's wordpress problem but i want to know how to give the wordpress high limits?